# How to compress or change the quality of an image using FileImage in DecorationImage?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm creating an application in which I'm using some `DecorationImage`. My images are really slow to appear and sometimes blinking in my ListView. Is there a way to compress them ?

I know there is the parameter on `Image.file` but it can't be used in a `DecorationImage` widget.

```
child : Container(
          height: 350.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: FileImage(File(item.image)),
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              fit: BoxFit.cover
            ),
```

Comment: how big is `File(item.image)`?

Comment: @pskink It's basically a picture taken with a phone, from 1Mo to almost 4Mo with my phone.

Comment: so no wonder that `"My images are really slow to appear and sometimes blinking in my ListView"` - make small thumbnails and use them

Comment: @pskink Sure I am aware of that, and that my question, I would like to compress this file in memory before displaying it.

Comment: tried to search [flutter packages](https://pub.dartlang.org/)?

Comment: My thought were that the option is available with `Image.file` so I was looking about a vanilla way to handle before looking at flutter pub, maybe by changing the way I am displaying it. (Not an ImageProvider but an Image for example)

Comment: I did, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It doesn't seems doing that, it's still so slow to load. Another way would be to create a smaller image in the AppDirectory, but it will take some phone space if there are too much images.

Comment: maybe try this: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image - it has `copyResize` function as shown in the docs at the bottom

Comment: "I would like to compress this file in memory before displaying it" ... If you do this *when* you're trying to display the images, that won't help at all (and is very likely to make things even slower).  If you want quality or size reduction to help, you need to do it *in advance* (possibly with a separate tool) so that the total time saved by doing many loads/decodes exceeds the time spent performing those reduction.